# Jquery + PHP Function called by $_GET that need $_POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, function

i've a PHP function like this:

```
function setUser()
{
    $userName=$_POST['userName'];
    $userSurname=$_POST['userSurname'];
    //code...
}
```

I call this function with an address like: ?index.php&module=registration

So, how do i call with jquery $_GET['module'] to recall the setUser(); function and to pass it all POST parameters that i need? Can you please make me an example?

Thanks and sorry for my bad english!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#button").click(function(e){
    //e.preventDefault();
    $.post('index.php?module=registration',{
        userName: 'test',
        userSurname: 'test'},
        function(data){
             //callback;
    });
}
```

that would be a simple jquery script to post the data. Presumably you will be grabbing the values of the post parameters dynamically from some page fields and feed it to the post function (something like `$("#name").val()`). More info at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

I also added the click event, because most likely you will have this attached to a button, which when clicked will post the data (if you are using submit button you will have to uncomment the preventDefault line).

Comment: Nice, is possible to do that with $.ajax?

Comment: it is the same, `$.post` is a shortcut for `$.ajax` call with `type: 'POST'`. Unless you need to define additional features of the request I would just stick to `$.get` and `$.post` as they are quicker and simpler to use

Answer (score 0):

set the `type` in your ajax call to `POST`

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'index.php',
    data: { module: 'registration' }
}).done( function( data ) {
     // do something if needed
});
```

Comment: if you look at the question, 'module' is a GET parameter, not POST, and he needs to POST two other values...

Answer (score 0):

To get parameters with jquery manipulate the `location.search` and get whatever parameter you need by simple string manipulations.

& then for posting values use jquery ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'index.php',
    data: { userName: 'test', userSurname: 'test' },
    success: function(return_value) {
        //values returned from ajax
    }
});
```